# Theory of groups

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can someone help me with this question,

"Is the subset of symmetries of a square consisting rotation  is subgroup?"

My idea is that this is a subgroup but i have problem on how to explain it with words. Thank you

Comment: Flipping what??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to apply a subgroup test.  The most straightforward one is the following:

- Is the subset closed under composition?  (Is the composition of two rotations also a rotation?)
- Is the subset closed under inversion? (Is the inverse of a rotation also a rotation?)

In general, any subset that is closed under composition and inversion is a subgroup.

e: Ethan Bolker has reminded me that if you're being careful, you need to check that the subset is nonempty, too.

Comment: Check too that it's not empty (picky picky).